# Expand content to fill DIV and at the same time "stay" within div - vaadin 7

Tags: html, vaadin

I have a VerticalPanel with a Padding of 25px - it has a Table as first component and TabSheet as second.

If I don't specify Expansion Ratio both Components gets a height of 50% automatically like this:

```
<div class="expand">
 <div class="v-slot" style="height:50%"><table>.......</table></div>
 <div class="v-slot" style="height:50%"><tabSheet>.......</tabSheet></div>
</div>
```

, and the VerticalLayout is filled out and the Padding is 'working'. - Super.. BUT

I want to have the Table (1st component) to take up as much needed space as it requires, and then the 2nd component (TabSheet) should take up a 100% of what is left. The problem is however that when I set Expand Ratio on the VerticalLayout to 1f `setExpandRatio(tabs, 1f)` for the 2nd component the HTML becomes:

```
<div class="expand">
 <div class="v-slot"><table>.......</table></div>
 <div class="v-slot" style="height:100%"><tabSheet>.......</tabSheet></div>
</div>
```

AND now the Padding (25px) of the VerticalLayout is not 'working' anymore - the TabSheet expands out of the VerticalLayout at the "bottom".

How can I achieve the desired behavior? - sounds like a very common issue - first component gets 1st priority and 2nd gets 100% of what is left ..

Comment: Is the padding your own CSS, because you should leave padding to Vaadin, using `setSpacing(true)` and/or `setMargin(true)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use CSS padding with `VerticalLayout`, that breaks Vaadin layouting as you can see. Instead of that you should either enable spacing or marging for the layout by saying

```
layout.setSpacing(true);
```

or

```
layout.setMargin(true);
```

If you want to modify default Vaadin spacing or margin values for your `VerticalLayout`, its possible by using a special CSS.

Let's say that your layout has style name `mymargins`, the you can control its margin size with the following CSS:

```
.mymargins.v-margin-left   {padding-left:   10px;}
.mymargins.v-margin-right  {padding-right:  20px;}
.mymargins.v-margin-top    {padding-top:    40px;}
.mymargins.v-margin-bottom {padding-bottom: 80px;}
```

It's possible to control `VerticalLayout`'s spacing with the following kind of CSS:

```
.v-vertical > .v-spacing {
   height: 30px;
}
```